# How can I assign the price value in Switch case?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is it suitable to use Switch to assign the price? If it's possible how can I do it. I know for switch case there must be a statement but I'm not sure about assigning values and get the value.

```
float one = 244.50f, two = 125.75f, three = 323.33f, four = 46.29f, five = 3323.65f, price; 
int choice, quantity, yn;

System.out.print("Please enter the assigned number of the item sold: "); 
choice = display.nextInt();

switch(choice){ 
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break; 
        case 3:
            break; 
        case 4:
            break; 
        case 5:
            break;

} // end of switch case

System.out.print("Please enter the quantity of the item sold: "); 
quantity = display.nextInt();

System.out.print("Price is: ");
```

I expect an output when the user enters 1 get 244.50f and so on.

Comment: declare a float before the switch. set the value of the float in the case blocks

Answer (score 4):

Use a Map instead its better

```
 var map = Map.of(1, 244.50f, 2, 125.75f); // and like so you can fill the map
 var somefloat = map.get(1);
 // or you can use 
 var somefloat = map.getOrDefault(1, 0f);
```

---

The example is in java 10+

Answer (score 3):

Altough this is an answer on its own, its is also an addition to the one from YCF_L.

If you are not using Java 10 with `Map#of`, you can use the following:

```
private float[] prices = {
        244.50f,
        125.75f,
        323.33f,
        46.29f,
        3323.65f
};

private float getPrice(int choice) {
    if (choice < 0 || choice >= prices.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invaid choice");
    }
    return prices[choice - 1];
}
```

Comment: `--choice` seems a bit fishy I suggest just using `choice - 1`

Answer (score 3):

Just for your information and educational purpose. Since the last java-12 release the switch expression is available in [preview language feature](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12). It could look like:

```
float price = switch (choice) {
    case 1 -> 244.50f;
    case 2 -> 125.75f;
    case 3 -> 323.33f;
    case 4 -> 46.29f;
    case 5 -> 3323.65f;
    default -> 0;
};
System.out.println(price);
```

See more [**JEP 325: Switch Expressions (Preview)**](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8192963)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int choice = 5; 

        float  price = 0; 
        switch (choice) { 
        case 1: 
            price = 244.50f; 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            price = 125.75f; 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            price = 323.33f; 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            price = 46.29f; 
            break; 
        case 5: 
            price = 3323.65f; 
            break; 
        default: 
            break; 
        } 
        System.out.println(price); 
    } 
} 
May be this one help you
```